# Displaying Task-Related Legends on a Grantt Chart with Dates in am5chart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

I'm currently using the Gantt chart with dates example from am5chart in my project https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/.

However, I'm having trouble implementing a legend that is related to the task data in the chart.

What I'm looking to do is create a list of tasks that will be displayed as legends on the chart. When a user clicks on a task in the legend, the corresponding series that is associated with that task should be hidden or shown on the chart.

I've already tried looking for a solution online, but I haven't been able to find one that suits my needs. Can someone please provide me with some guidance on how to achieve this?

To summarize, I need help with the following:

1. Adding a legend to my Gantt chart with dates example from am5chart
2. Displaying a list of tasks as legends on the chart
3. Toggling the visibility of the corresponding series when a task is clicked in the legend.